# Laravel - Eloquent eager loading access parent table reference(alias) in child query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

Trying to get subject wise attendance of students. But the where condition is not working inside closure function because `students.id` is not available there.

```php
Student::with(['semesters.subjects'=>function($q){
        $q->withCount(['attendance'=>function($q2) {
                $q2->where('attendance.student_id','=','students.id');
         }]);
}])->paginate(10);
```

What can be the best optimized query for in this case?

Comment: If you don't find a solution, you can use raw SQL. Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects) (mind the version you are using)

Comment: can you add the `attendance` and other relations?

Comment: `attendance` have relationship with `subjects` and also with `students`.
Here is `attendance` table `id | subject_id | student_id | date | status`

Comment: Can you add the exact relations as in the models? Is there any relation between subjects and attendance? [Edit your question to add details rather than commenting].

Comment: Are `semesters` and `subjects` `HasMany` relationships?